# Connection Pool using HikariCP for SnowFlake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, connection-pooling

I am trying to test connection pool using HikariCP against SnowFlake.

I have kept the pool size and idle size, both, set to 5. However I observed that while getting a connection, every time its creating a new connection. For example , If i make 8 connection, i could see 8 test sql query being executed on Snowflake (I checked it in history.). My expectation was it should not create more that 5 (pool size) connection and this is justified by only 5 test sql query on snowflake.

Does anyone have any clue?

**Configuration:**
micronaut:
application:
name: mnsfpoc
netty:
default:
allocator:
max-order: 3

datasources:
default:
url: jdbc:snowflake://xxx.azure.snowflakecomputing.com/?warehouse=xx&db=xx&schema=xx&role=xx
username: xxxx
password: xxxx
driverClassName: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver
maximum-pool-size: 5
minimum-idle: 5
pool-name: mnsfconn-pool
connection-test-query: select 3

**Code to get connection:**

@Singleton
public class RestDao extends BaseDao {

```
@Inject
private DataSource dataSource;

public String greet(String name) throws Exception {
    Connection conn1 = dataSource.getConnection();
    close(conn1);
    return "Hello " + name + "!!";
}
```

}

Thanks
Rakhs

Comment: Can you post a sample of your code?

Comment: Thansk for responding. Updated the Q with details.

Comment: Do you have any logging enabled? With the provided information it is hard to say why the max pool size is not respected.

Comment: I am oast this. It was my bad to use connection-test-query , instead of connection-init-query.

Comment: However , I am facing a different issue where , Two datasourceConfiguration bean are getting created , resulting into two different Pools taking number of connection to double the intende size. any Idea?

Comment: [io.micronaut.configuration.jdbc.hikari.DatasourceConfiguration@2ceb80a1] from definition [Definition: io.micronaut.configuration.jdbc.hikari.DatasourceConfiguration] with qualifier [@Named('default')]

Comment: Created bean [io.micronaut.configuration.jdbc.hikari.DatasourceConfiguration@3baa6af1] from definition [Definition: io.micronaut.configuration.jdbc.hikari.DatasourceConfiguration] with qualifier [@Named('default')]